# How to evaluate the bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, error, bias-variance-tradeoff

How can you evaluate the bias-variance tradeoff by looking at the train error and at the test error?

Comment: You cannot.  Bias and variance are not things that can actually be computes, since they depend on knowing the true regression function.  They are instead conceptual tools for understanding the behaviour of our models, and giving us language to discuss them.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of this: if my train error is v small and my test error isn't probably i'm overfitting, so large variance and supposedly small bias? Is this wrong?

Comment: What could you say about the behaviour of a model in terms of these two indexes, looking at train and test error?
Also, REALLY dumb question: how am I calculating the errors? Am I not considering for both train and test set a set which has, for example, the actual, real classification label? So I can calculate these errors. And the test error is an estimate of the error I might get with other unseen data (of wich I really want to know the label)